Media Attachment Pages Redirect to Media Files After Migrating to WordPress Multisite
I've created a WordPress multisite network and successfully imported sites into it. On each site, I need media attachment pages enabled, so each image should have its dedicated attachment page. However, after migrating the sites to the multisite setup, media URLs that previously led to attachment pages are now redirecting directly to the media files themselves.
I've checked all relevant settings, including the media attachment options in the Yoast SEO plugin. While Yoast SEO recommends disabling attachment pages, I've re-enabled the setting specifically to allow media attachment pages and tested toggling it off and on again, but the redirects to the media file URLs persist.
Here’s what I’ve tried to resolve the issue so far:

Switched web servers from Nginx to Apache, but the problem remains.

Disabled plugins one by one, including the SEO plugin, with no
success.


I'm looking for insights into why this redirection is happening or suggestions for troubleshooting this further. Any guidance on settings or configuration adjustments specific to WordPress Multisite that might be affecting media attachment pages would be greatly appreciated.

According to the Make WP.org blog listing out changes a major release turned off attachment pages for new sites by default, keeping them active only for old ones, and providing code snippets for enforcing or disabling this behaviour. You'll want to ensure this is set how you would prefer before investigating further

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2023/10/16/changes-to-attachment-pages/ - I found the given entry, thank you. And I have wp_attachment_pages_enabled set to 1 and they still don't work.
